# Kernel panic during sleep

Tags: sleep-wake, crash, monterey, kernel-panic

After updating to macOS 12.6.1, my MacBook Pro 13" 2020 has started to experience kernel panics during sleep.

Normally, I have my Mac go to sleep at 11:30 pm and wake at 7:30 am with the Mac open (not in clamshell mode). The first time it happened I just figured it was a random event, but then it happened the very next day. I copied the crash report to a text file, just in case. This continued happening for a few days so I figured that the recent update has changed something. My guess is that there is some process happening during sleep that is causing the kernel panic. So I opted to set my Mac to shut down instead of sleep.

Everything seemed to be working fine without finding any kernel panics in the morning. One day I was busy doing things here in the house and the Mac went into sleep mode and I came back to find that it had rebooted. Once I logged back in, I find yet another crash report waiting for me. The odd thing is that this only happens when the Mac is open and goes into sleep mode. It doesn't crash if the Mac is in clamshell mode.

The crash happens at random times during sleep. Once it happened within 30 mins of sleeping while other times it will happen several hours after sleeping. I have rebooted into Recovery Mode and run Disk Utility with no problems detected.

Can someone help me diagnose what is happening and provide a possible fix? Is there something that I can do short of a complete reinstall?

Latest crash report with kexts truncated:

```
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff80044291f1): AMDFramebufferVIB::setPowerState(0xffffff94f6ad6000 : 0xffffff7f9cd58892, 0 -> 2) timed out after 45299 ms @IOServicePM.cpp:5524
Panicked task 0xffffff94f57f1670: 298 threads: pid 0: kernel_task
Backtrace (CPU 0), panicked thread: 0xffffff9027933000, Frame : Return Address
0xffffffffd7e9ba30 : 0xffffff8003c7de9d
0xffffffffd7e9ba80 : 0xffffff8003de0556
0xffffffffd7e9bac0 : 0xffffff8003dcf8c3
0xffffffffd7e9bb10 : 0xffffff8003c1da70
0xffffffffd7e9bb30 : 0xffffff8003c7e26d
0xffffffffd7e9bc50 : 0xffffff8003c7da26
0xffffffffd7e9bcb0 : 0xffffff80045145e3
0xffffffffd7e9bda0 : 0xffffff80044291f1
0xffffffffd7e9be00 : 0xffffff80044289b9
0xffffffffd7e9be10 : 0xffffff8004442d6e
0xffffffffd7e9be50 : 0xffffff80044277f8
0xffffffffd7e9be70 : 0xffffff8003cd0f15
0xffffffffd7e9bee0 : 0xffffff8003cd1fe2
0xffffffffd7e9bfa0 : 0xffffff8003c1d19e

Process name corresponding to current thread (0xffffff9027933000): kernel_task
Boot args: chunklist-security-epoch=0 -chunklist-no-rev2-dev chunklist-security-epoch=0 -chunklist-no-rev2-dev

Mac OS version:
21G217

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 21.6.0: Thu Sep 29 20:12:57 PDT 2022; root:xnu-8020.240.7~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 54B44BAE-1625-30CC-80B0-29E4966EFFDC
KernelCache slide: 0x0000000003a00000
KernelCache base:  0xffffff8003c00000
Kernel slide:      0x0000000003a10000
Kernel text base:  0xffffff8003c10000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8003b00000
System model name: MacBookPro16,3 (Mac-E7203C0F68AA0004)
System shutdown begun: NO
Hibernation exit count: 0

System uptime in nanoseconds: 31311422155528
Last Sleep:           absolute           base_tsc          base_nano
  Uptime  : 0x00001c7a4231efc2
  Sleep   : 0x00001c6f49bc2349 0x0000278b740ad6d8 0x00001c63240c68a7
  Wake    : 0x00001c6f551b7eca 0x000028c85173076c 0x00001c6f53c2c693
Compressor Info: 3% of compressed pages limit (OK) and 11% of segments limit (OK) with 3 swapfiles and OK swap space
Zone info:
  Zone map: 0xffffff8027f57000 - 0xffffffa027f57000
  . PGZ   : 0xffffff8027f57000 - 0xffffff8029f58000
  . VM    : 0xffffff8029f58000 - 0xffffff84f6757000
  . RO    : 0xffffff84f6757000 - 0xffffff868ff57000
  . GEN0  : 0xffffff868ff57000 - 0xffffff8b5c757000
  . GEN1  : 0xffffff8b5c757000 - 0xffffff9028f57000
  . GEN2  : 0xffffff9028f57000 - 0xffffff94f5757000
  . GEN3  : 0xffffff94f5757000 - 0xffffff99c1f57000
  . DATA  : 0xffffff99c1f57000 - 0xffffffa027f57000
  Metadata: 0xffffffffd9fee000 - 0xfffffffff9fee000
  Bitmaps : 0xfffffffff9fee000 - 0xfffffffffffee000

last started kext at 21334356814277: >usb.cdc.acm   5.0.0 (addr 0xffffff7f9ca1d000, size 12288)
last stopped kext at 21518742685317: >usb.serial    6.0.0 (addr 0xffffff7f9ca93000, size 20480)
```

Comment: 12.6 and 12.6.1 have been more panics for me than all of Sierra to Catalina combined. I haven’t found solutions. Either go back to 12.5.X or forward to 13?

Comment: This is a bug in the AMD accelerated graphics driver that's built-in to macOS. You can see that it occurs on the way up from sleep to wake. It is Apple's bug and hopefully one that is fixed in later versions, as James mentions.